# Trying to change even list links css?

Tags: html, css

So here's what I was trying to do

CSS:

```
li:nth-child(2n) {
background-color:gray;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

This works well. But when I try

```
li>a:nth-child(2n) {
    color:white;
}
```

This doesn't work IDK why?

Comment: `li>a:nth-child(2n)` that means every second element `a` inside the elemnt `li` is gonna be white. but you only have 1 `a` tag inside your `li`

Comment: It doesnt work as it appears syntactically but works by taking all outer evens then having their inner elements

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *even rule* to target all the *even* children, like this.

```
li:nth-child(even) a {
   color: white;
}
```

Here's a reference: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja you only have one "a" child. There's no way " li>a:nth-child(2n)" is going to work, the "2n" rule must be on li, unless you plan to have 2 siblings "a"

Comment: Yeah i got it now thanks guys that helped

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja glad it worked ;) don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you are saying "the nth li" of which there are several. In the second example, you are saying "the nth a in a li" of which there is only one.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it worked taking all lis together strange

```
   li:nth-child(2n)>a
   { color:white}
```

Comment: this is actually my code, thanks!

Comment: Yeah u updated now